# Is there a way to check what's in the cache for Windows OS's?

Tags: windows, caching, filesystems

I would like to see what is in the cache at any given time. Is there a way to check what's in the cache?

Comment: Yes, to know if something is in the cache, access it and see how much time it takes :)

Comment: Ha, yeah and I'm just going to go and check everything I possibly could think would be in cache. Not practical buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the kernel debugger with the !filecache command.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? I went to http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.Mspx and there are a ton of files included with that. Which file should I run? Is the !filecache command a parameter or command I type in once I get within another program?

Comment: kdb.exe and yes, once you are inside the debugger. Also, you need to setup the machine to enable kernel debugging. Good luck!

Comment: Kd.exe or Windbg.exe actually :)  This isn't going to be easy though; can I ask your scenario?

Comment: Yeah, my scenario is that I'm writing a bunch of files to disk and I'm comparing the write times. I want to make sure that caching is not messing up my test results.